# BatchJobs results gives the function result * -1 + job#?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, hpc, lsf

I am running a minimal example using BatchJobs, and the results are not as expected. I'm using the [global_config settings](https://github.com/tudo-r/BatchJobs/wiki/Configuration), with debug=TRUE. I am running the following code in R on my HPC server:

```
library(BatchJobs)
reg <- makeRegistry(id = "batchtest")

batchMap(reg, identity, 1)
submitJobs(reg)
showStatus(reg)

load("batchtest-files/jobs/01/1-result.RData")
1-result
[1] 0
```

If I run batchMap(reg, identity, 2) the result is -1, and with batchMap(reg, identity, 3) the result is -2.
Any ideas why this might be happening? The identity function should just return the argument (so it should be 1 for the code above). I find the same issue with other functions. For example, if I use mean(rnorm(100, mean=100)) for the function I send to batchMap, I end up with results around -99. If I run this on multiple nodes, the results from each node are around -100 + node number (so the results from the 5th node are around -95).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try an `ls()`. Probably the correct result from the `load` command is stored in the variable `result`. When you calculate `1-result` you will get exactly the results you described.

Comment: Oh, that's totally it! I was imagining the variable name would be the same as the file name, even though of course you can't have a - in a variable name in R. I guess I've been staring at this too long. Thanks so much for your help!